# React component running even when the react app is stopped

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I have a simple contact form in my app and I just noticed something interesting.

Even when I quit my app (`pressing q or ctrl + c` (I'm using Vite)), still I can submit the form successfully.

Why is it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vite is development tooling and one thing that Vite is doing is making sure you instantly see the changes that you make during development. (It's doing a bit more than that, but we'd have to go into [the details](https://vitejs.dev))

React is essentially just Javascript, so once all the logic has been loaded by the client browser, it can be used. So your app will just work exactly the same way, but will not be updated with any changes that you make. The same way as when a user uses your application with your latest production build.